# How to make a drop down select field required in a controller and blade template in Laravel 8

Tags: php, html, laravel

I have a form that is my blade template and it has a drop-down select field. I want it to be required but even after using the "required" attribute in the form and also in the controller's validation rules, the forms still submit an empty column to the database. How can I make it mandatory?

In Blade Template

```
                            <select name="county" id="county" class="custom-select" required>
                              <option selected>Select County</option>
                                    <option value="mombasa">001-Mombasa</option>
                                    <option value="kwale">002-Kwale</option>
                                    <option value="kilifi">003-Kilifi</option>
                                    <option value="tana_river">004-Tana River</option>
                            </select>
```

In Controller's Validation

```
protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make(
            $data,
            [
            'county'   => 'required',
            ]
        );
    }
```

In User Model

```
protected $fillable = [
        'county',
    ];

protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'county'    => $data['county'],
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Also add the controller's "saving" code here.

Comment: @Martin Osusky protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'county' => $data['county'],
        ]);
    }
}

Comment: public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('county')->nullable();
    
    }

Comment: I mean to the question.

Comment: It still doesn't make sense, where do you extract data from the http request? Add that code to the question

Comment: I have put sections of the code (In blade template, validation in the controller and user model that inserts data to the database.

Comment: If you have an example of validating a select field please share, thanks. I'm not a very experienced programmer.

Comment: I mean literally other functions from the controller, not just the validator. To be sure, add the appropriate part of the routing (to the question).